# Debian: why are the suggested upgrades from apt-get and synaptic different?

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I am running Debian Jessie, and this is the content of my sources.list file:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

I can update the system with *apt-get update* and *apt-get upgrade* from the command line with no problem. However, when I try to update from *synaptic* (the GUI package manager), using the *Mark All Upgrades* button, I get lots of suggested changes, including the removal of gnome, gnome-core, and others:

[image]

These are the contents of synaptic's *software sources* settings:

[image]

[image]

So, the question is: **why are the suggested upgrades from apt-get and synaptic different?** Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synaptic is a GUI front-end for the apt-get application and it uses the `apt-get dist-upgrade` feature for its upgrading by default as opposed to `apt-get upgrade` that you are using from the command line.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

The reason the recommendations from the processes are different is that `dist-upgrade` tries to intelligently resolve package dependencies and any issues more deeply than the generic `upgrade` feature.

In my own experience, I have noticed massive removal recommendations like the ones shown when I am removing/changing elements in different desktop environments.

Comment: I did _apt-get dist-upgrade_ and now both synaptic and apt-get match, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you install (or upgrade) a package with `apt-get`, **recommended** packages are installed automatically, whereas **suggested** packages are not installed.  This can be changed by using the options `--no-install-recommends` and/or `--install-suggests`.  On the other hand, `synaptic` has an option for automatically installing **recommended** packages in its Settings dialog.  Normally, this could be the only reason I can think of for the different behavior of the two package managers.

What strikes me as odd is that `synaptic` reports your `ftp.debian.org` and `security.debian.org` sources as "other software".  Assuming you are on jessie, they should be your main, officially supported software sources.  It seems to me, therefore, that `synaptic` is somehow confused to think that you're still on wheezy and this is the reason why it tries to mess up with your installed packages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. As I noted in my comment for the answer above, after doing _apt-get dist-upgrade_ now both synaptic and apt-get agree; however, it seems synaptic still "believes" I'm on wheezy, I can not even check the boxes for main, officially supported sources...